# Certificate errors don't offer the option to "continue to website (not recommended)"

Tags: internet-explorer-9, certificate

I'm using IE9 and trying to access a trusted page with an security certificate not from a trusted authority.  I know I can permanently add the certificate once I access the page.  The trouble is, there is no option to "continue to website (not recommended)".

How can I restore this option?  I read something about a policy, but I can't find the setting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this.  I had to run IE9 as an Administrator, then I could pass the certificate error and install the certificate manually as a trusted website.  Now I can access the site without problems as a regular user.